# Spring cloud config and xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Example given here 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

works fine including refresh of properties when using RestController in Java file. However, when I am injecting the properties in **xml file**, it is unable to recognize the property.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'exchange' in value "${exchange}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
```

Config:

```
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
      channel="getAccount" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" exchange-name="${exchange}"
      routing-key="facade.listener.key" mapped-request-headers="http_requestUrl,X-B3-TraceId,X-B3-SpanId,X-Span-Name" />
```

And proprties file in GIT repository is

```
exchange=trace.log.topic
```

does spring boot and spring cloud config support xml variable injection as well?

Comment: working fine now...issue is resolved. Not sure what was the issue.